# Ansible's docker_secret module don't accept variable in data field

Tags: ansible, docker-secrets

I'm using Ansible 2.4

In a playbook, I retrieve a secret from an Ansible vault file and try to inject this secret as a swarm secret using ***docker_secret*** module:

```
- hosts: managers
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Include secrets vars in task
    include_vars: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vault/vault.yml"
    name: secrets

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ secrets }}"

  - name: Set Docker secrets in SWARM
    docker_secret:
      name: "secrets.properties"
      data: "{{ secrets }}"
      state: present
```

The debug outputs the correct value but the docker_secret job is crashingtelling me that there is no "secrets" attribute.

> PLAY [managers]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ********************************************************* ok: [test1]
>
> TASK [secrets]
>   ***************************************************************** ok: [test1]
>
> TASK [debug]
>   ******************************************************************* ok: [test1] => {
>       "msg": "***secrets.gitJenkinsPassword=MY_SECRET_PASSWORD***" }
>
> TASK [Set Docker secrets in SWARM]
>   ********************************************* fatal: [test1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to node1.mycompany.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout":
>   "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_9JUi1H/ansible_module_docker_secret.py\", line 283, in
>   \r\n    main()\r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_9JUi1H/ansible_module_docker_secret.py\", line 278, in
>   main\r\n    SecretManager(client, results)()\r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_9JUi1H/ansible_module_docker_secret.py\", line 170, in
>   **call**\r\n    self.present()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9JUi1H/ansible_module_docker_secret.py\", line 209, in
>   present\r\n    secret = self.get_secret()\r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_9JUi1H/ansible_module_docker_secret.py\", line 177, in
>   get_secret\r\n    secrets = self.client.secrets(filters={'name':
>   self.name})\r\nAttributeError: 'AnsibleDockerClient' object has no
>   attribute 'secrets'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}   to retry,
>   use: --limit
>   @/var/jenkins_home/workspace/deploy/ansible/playbooks/swarm.retry

Comment: Is this `Requirements (on host that executes module) docker-py >= 2.1.0` met?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Konstantin_Surovov, this is a docker-py library version issue.  In fact it only works with docker-py 2.4 or higherr because there is a bug on the secret feature in 2.1